# Smoothness of a dataset with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a sample of example of two data as below;

[image]

If I was to plot the two, Data A would have a much smoother line graph and data B would have more spikey graph. How can I use pandas to sort of deternimne/differentiate the smoothness of dataset e.g with a calculation on the data and giving it an index which I can equate to the smoothness f the data. I looked for a solution and there was a suggestion using difference of Standard deviation. This was based on R. Any ideas on this? What sort of calculation would give me what i want? Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: You have to distinguish between first, what equation you want to use to quantify smoothness, and second, how you will implement that equation in some specific language. Maybe post the R solution, and think about whether that quantification is what you want, in which case translating to pandas should be straightforward.

Comment: One of the proposed solution i saw somewhere  was To estimate the roughness of an array, take the squared difference of the normalized differences, and divide by 4. This gives you scale-independence (because of the normalization), and ignores trends (because of using the second difference).

firstD = diff(x)
normFirstD = (firstD - mean(firstD)) / sd(firstD)
roughness = (diff(normFirstD) ** 2) / 4
Zero will be perfect smoothness, 1 is maximal roughness.

You then either use the sum of this measure, or its mean, depending on whether you want your roughness measure to be length-independent

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Standard deviation doesn't necessarily mean smoothness in the sense you seem to mean. A straight line graph (y=x) A:1 B:2 C:3 D:4 would be smooth for what you mean right? Whereas A:4 B:1 C:3 B:2 would not (it would go up and down/change direction). I think what you are looking for is a change of slope calculation (derivative of the function at different points or gradient).

In this case it's actually quite simple. Just calculate the sum of the absolute difference between each point. The one with the greatest total is more "spikey".

You can shift the data (pandas.shift), subtract the shift from the original, take the absolute value and then the sum.